# Hierarchical list with many nesting levels, horizontal lay-out: have parent accommodate to childres width

Tags: css

I have an extremely nested, hierarchical, list (it contains biological data on ordering of species). See the example, where I selected only three of the possible 10 levels of nesting.

I'd like to display this list horizontally, as an organizational chart that has been rotated 90 degrees.

[image: Example of the hierarchical list]

I *can* get the exact right lay-out when I apply a width to each and every child-ul. Fortunately, the tree is generated by JavaScript and applying inline styles is easy. (As such:)

```
                    <ul  class="wrapper" style="width: 120px;">
```

However, I realy would like to get rid of these inline styles, because the whole management of the tree would become so much easier without them. (Consider the possibility of showing/hiding child levels or even removing complete levels of organisation)

As you can see in the fiddles, removing the inline styled width, doesn't work. Which is strange, because I've set a width for the label. ***How can I make the parent divs accommodate to width of the child elements, however deep they have been nested***?

Here on stack overflow, several similar question have been asked. These suggest setting *float: left* and *position:relative*. But, too bad, it doens't work...

http://jsfiddle.net/ideogram/27kNA/5/  (without inline styles)

http://jsfiddle.net/ideogram/zFMyZ/2/ (with inline styles)

Basically, my question boils down to: in the following css/html, ***how do I get rid of the inline width while maintaining the desired lay-out?***

```
<head>  

    <style type="text/css">
        .label{
            width: 120px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .wrapper{
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding-left: 0;
        }

        .label, .wrapper{
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 110px;

        }

        .taxon{
            display: inline-block;
            overflow: hiden;
            outline: 1px dotted #ddd;
            margin: 5px 0;
            text-align: left;
        }
    </style>
```

```
<ul class="wrapper" style="width: 360px;">
    <li class="taxon ">
        <div class="label">Balaenopteridae</div>
        <ul class="wrapper" style="width: 240px;">
            <li class="taxon ">
                <div class="label">Balaenoptera</div>
                <ul  class="wrapper" style="width: 120px;">
                    <li class="taxon">
                        <div class="label">Balaenoptera acutorostrata</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="taxon">
                        <div class="label">Balaenoptera borealis</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="taxon">
                        <div class="label">Balaenoptera edeni</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="taxon">
                <div class="label">Megaptera</div>
                <ul  class="wrapper" style="width: 120px;">
                    <li class="taxon">
                        <div class="label">Megaptera novaeangliae</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="taxon">
                        <div class="label">Megaptera whatever</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your selectors as follows and remove any defined widths. The key point is `display: table-cell` *et al* of the same family.
**Fiddle sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/pLUns/

```
.label{
    border-radius: $taxon-margin;
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.label, .wrapper{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;             
}

.taxon{
    display: table-row;
    overflow: hidden;
    outline: 1px dotted #ddd;
    text-align: left;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The crucial change is indeed display: table-cell to the labels and the wrapper (who are siblings) and display: table-row to the taxon, who is their parent.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in HTML few things size to their contents. Most elements calculate their size based on the size of their parents.

The ones's that do size to their contents include (off the top of my head): tables, floated elements, absolutely/fixedly positioned elements. Perhaps there's something else too, but I don't remember it right now.

In your case I'd suggest using a javascript-generated table instead of a list. I know, I know - not semantic and all that. But the visual requirements are such that anything short of table or specific widths will fail.

That's because an element needs not only consider their own content size, but also the size of their siblings. After all, if there are 3 elements in your 2nd level, you'd want them all to be the same width, right?

If you have severe allergy against tables, you might be able to slip through with `display: table-cell`, though I don't know how you'd do the rowspans that you need.

Comment: Thanks, putting display: table-cell is indeed the way to go. Your answer was first, but Nit's answer is more epxlicit, that's why mark his answer as THE answer.

Comment: A JavaScript generated table, by the way, would not solve my problem. I tried that approach. In this situation it is crucial that the way the html is organized, mimics the data structure to keep my JavaScript as neat and tidy as possible.